# update symfony field on form submit

Tags: symfony

lets say that i have a simple form like this:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('field', 'text');

        // this is select
        $builder->add('field2', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(),
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        ));
    }
}
```

now i want to update `field2` options on form submit.
so the flow is:

1. visit the page with empty form
2. fill `field1` and submit the form
3. form will 'fail validation' as it is missing value for `field2`, but this time it ll render the form with options for `field2` based on submitted value from `field1`
4. value for `field2` is selected and together with `field1` (filled in step 2) submitted
5. form validation pass

### What i've tried

1.

[How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

here they discuss how to add new field based on submitted form, but i need to update already existing field. so in event function something like:

```
$form->get('field2')->**update**('choices', array(1=>'test'));
```

however i could not figure out how to do this as there is no function `**update**`

i can re-create field2 in form event like this:

```
$builder->get('field2')->remove();
$builder->add('field2', 'choice', array(...));
```

but this doesn't seems right.

2.

getting value of `field1` in controller and pass it to my `MyType` as custom option and based on that either set or not `choices` on `field2` during form creation.

my problem here is, that if i do this, i have to get the value directly from `$request->query->get('field1');` and this is wrong. i need to let the form to process request and than get the value via `$form->getData()->getField1()` so the form has a chance to process my `DataTransformer` attached to `field1`

my code in controller is standard code generated by symfony2:

```
$entity = new Entity();
$form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
$form->handleRequest($request);
$value = $form->getData()->getField1();
```

and now its too late to pass `$value` to form builder as the form is already created in `createCreateForm()`

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to replace, in your first tried solution, this block :

```
$builder->get('field2')->remove();
$builder->add('field2', 'choice', array(...));
```

By this one :

```
$builder->remove('field2');
$builder->add('field2', 'choice', array(...));
```

Comment: hm i dont have a problem with that piece of code (either version yours or mine) the main question is, if this is the correct or the only solution? as it does not seems right to me

Comment: I think it's the only way to do what you need.

Comment: another problem with this solution is field order. if i remove the field im not able to re-add it into the same position, well not without additional bundle

Comment: Maybe you can, using a custom field type that you always add on your root form. And adding your form event on this sub-type, which add or not the choice field. The order won't change but it adds a child level to your form.

Comment: Does the field need to be removed? I always remember simply adding the field like normal (in buildForm) and then adding it again (with the updated data) in the event listener. "Re-adding" it actually just overrides. I could be wrong (I don't have it in front of me), but I always thought you could just overwrite the field in the listener. It's definitely true that you won't "modify" the choices, you'll add an entirely new field and overwrite the original :).